# Google+ API on devices with Android 4.1 or later

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I'm thinking of use this to interact with G+ circles:

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started

The question is, does it works in Android devices 4.1 or later?
Cause in the "get started" page says in prerequisites: A physical device to use for developing and testing because Google Play services can only be installed on an emulator with an AVD that runs Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

This apply only to AVD, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play Services supports Android devices running Android 2.3+ and emulated devices running Android 4.2.2+.

https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

Comment: About your edition in my post, sorry for bolding the text... I used that to mark as something that I copy from another place...